# Hardware question

Tags: discussion

I am looking into a super resolution project  ( [Increasing image resolution](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/4788/increasing-image-resolution) ) and was thinking of building a hardware to snap multiple pictures. A question about building a hardware definitely seems off topic to DSP. But who better to answer / give suggestions this than DSP folks? Should I post such questions? Where is such a question best suited?

Answer (score 3):

I think electronics.stackexchange.com would be a more suitable place for that.

Answer (score 0):

Questions about HDLs (Hardware Description Languages) such as Verilog or VHDL are welcome on https://stackoverflow.com/. HDLs are used for creating custom chips (ASIC) or programming FPGAs.

Any questions regarding discrete components is probably best served by https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.